# Returning the ETH from Smart Contract to Metamask (Bot scam)

Tags: metamask, cpp-ethereum, scam, bot

Unfortunately I was trying this scam bot and I transferred the ETH to the Smart Contract, it's my mistake. However I am not able to transfer back from Contract address to Metamask address.

The bot code: `https://telegra.ph/The-Best-Arbitrage-Strategy-Explained-in-Detail-02-27`

Is there anyway to get back my ETH back?
Contract address: 0xb5e9b31e0C0572d0e35E3831b6AA49a79aBb4b7f